# How to recursively search directories in a minimal shell (no grep, find, etc.)?

Tags: bash, shell, glob, qnx

I'm working with an embedded system running QNX that has a stripped-down shell (KSH).

I want to locate all run all executables on the filesystem that match the following:

```
*/shle/*-*_test
```

The "shle" directory may appear up to 4 levels deep under root. My current approach is to run the following commands:

```
for shle in ./shle ./*/shle ./*/*/shle ./*/*/*/shle
do
  for exe in $shle/*-*_test
  do
    echo running: $exe
    $exe
  done
done
```

Is there a cleaner or faster way of doing this? Are there commands other than `grep` and `find` that I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `find`, you can't do much better than what you did: enumerate the levels. If you needed to go down to arbitrary levels, you could do it with a recursive function (but watch out, recursion is tricky when all you have is global variables). Fortunately, with a known maximum depth, it's a lot simpler.

There's a little room for improvement: you'd better put double quotes around all variable substitutions, in case there's a filename somewhere that contains whitespace or special characters. And you aren't testing whether `$exe` is exists and executable (it could be the pattern `…/*-*_test` if that pattern doesn't match anything, or perhaps it could be a non-executable file).

```
for shle in shle */shle */*/shle */*/*/shle; do
  for exe in "$shle"/*-*_test; do
    test -x "$exe" && "$exe"
  done
done
```

If you don't even have `test` (if you have ksh, it's built-in, but if it's a stripped-down shell it might be missing), you might get away with a more complicated test to see if the pattern was expanded:

```
for shle in shle */shle */*/shle */*/*/shle; do
  for exe in "$shle"/*-*_test; do
    case "$exe" in
      */"*-*_test") :;;
      *) "$exe";;
    esac
  done
done
```

(I'm suprised that you don't have `find`, I thought QNX came with a full POSIX suite, but I'm unfamiliar with the QNX ecosystem, this could be a stripped-down version of the OS for a small device.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm not that worried about attempting to run an executable that doesn't exist (unless that is significantly slowing the whole process down). And yes, our QNX build is highly stripped to run on a small embedded device.

Comment: What do you mean by "enumerate the levels"?

Comment: @justus87 I meant what you're already doing: `shle`, that's one; `*/shle`, that's two; `*/*/shle`, that's three, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the *globstar* option and specifying **/shle to find the directories that are one or more levels deep.

From the ksh manpage:

```
          ∗      Matches any string, including the null string.  When used
                 for filename expansion, if the globstar option is on, two
                 adjacent  ∗'s  by itself will match all files and zero or
                 more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a  /
                 then only directories and subdirectories will match.
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that option is available to me (and no shopt to enable it), but thanks!